# EditText Values getting cleared on scrolling listview android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

```
public class Custom_Student_marks_list_faculty_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<MarksStudentListFacultyObject> {
    private Activity context;
    private List<MarksStudentListFacultyObject> studentlist;

    public Custom_Student_marks_list_faculty_adapter(Activity context,List<MarksStudentListFacultyObject> studentlist) {
        super(context,R.layout.custom_listview_marks_faculty,studentlist);
        this.context=context;
        this.studentlist=studentlist;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

       final  ViewHolder holder;
       if(convertView==null) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_marks_faculty, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_marks_faculty_stu_name_id);
           holder.marks = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_marks_faculty_stu_marks_id);
           String mark = holder.marks.getText().toString();

           MarksStudentListFacultyObject student_list = studentlist.get(position);

           holder.name.setText(student_list.getName());
           holder.marks.setText(mark);
           holder.marks.setTag(position);
           convertView.setTag(holder);
       }  else {
            holder =(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
       }

       holder.name.setText(studentlist.get(position).getName());
       holder.marks.setText(studentlist.get(position).getMakrs());

       return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView name;
    protected  EditText marks;
}
```

I have seen many solution for it but it is not working out for me. Every time on scrolling, `ListView` values are getting cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work...

```
public Custom_Student_marks_list_faculty_adapter(Activity context,List<MarksStudentListFacultyObject> studentlist) {
        super(context,R.layout.custom_listview_marks_faculty,studentlist);
        this.context=context;
        this.studentlist=studentlist;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        final  ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_marks_faculty, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_marks_faculty_stu_name_id);
           holder.marks = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_marks_faculty_stu_marks_id);
           convertView.setTag(holder);
       }  else {
            holder =(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
       }

           MarksStudentListFacultyObject student_list = studentlist.get(position);
           holder.name.setText(student_list.getName());
           //holder.marks.setText(student_list.getMarks());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Not Working Sir! values getting changed on Scrolling listview

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the edittext values again in your student list because of the recycling nature of list view and also set the value on each time getview method is called.

Something like:

```
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    final  ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_marks_faculty, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_marks_faculty_stu_name_id);
       holder.marks = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_marks_faculty_stu_marks_id);
       convertView.setTag(holder);
   }  else {
        holder =(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
   }

       MarksStudentListFacultyObject student_list = studentlist.get(position);
       holder.name.setText(student_list.getName());
      holder.marks.setText(student_list.getMarks());
      holder.marks.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int before, int count) {
            //set data to array when changed
            student_list.setMarks(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code for the list somewhere ? I think there could be another issue with the code. From what i understood, the edittext for marks needs to save the value when the view gets out of the screen, right? Theres another solution in which you can do  holder.setIsRecyclable(false); in recycler views but i'd advise against that.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

   if(convertView==null) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_marks_faculty, null);
   }

   TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_marks_faculty_stu_name_id);
   EditText marks = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_marks_faculty_stu_marks_id);

   name.setText(studentlist.get(position).getName());
   marks.setText(studentlist.get(position).getMakrs());

   return convertView;
}
```

**Edit :**

Override getCount() method in ArrayAdaptor:

```
@Override public int getCount(){ return studentlist.size(); }
```

Comment: Than the issue is not with your ArrayAdaptor, Issue is with your xml layout or data-set or any other part of code. Can you provide some more details ?

Comment: i have posted complete code of array adapter, u need xml code for inflated object?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

       final  ViewHolder holder;
       if(convertView==null) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_marks_faculty, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_marks_faculty_stu_name_id);
           holder.marks = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_marks_faculty_stu_marks_id);
                      convertView.setTag(holder);
       }  else {
            holder =(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
       }


      String mark = holder.marks.getText().toString();

           MarksStudentListFacultyObject student_list = studentlist.get(position);

           holder.name.setText(student_list.getName());
           holder.marks.setText(mark);


          return convertView;
    }
}
```